# Fabricjs canvas inside Angular Material Tabs doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fabricjs, angular-material

I have been trying to use Fabric.canvas inside angular material tabs (material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs) but that doesn't seem to work. 
Finally I want there to be multiple tabs with multiple canvases. For now I'm trying it with only one tab.

[This code without tabs seems to wok just fine, it allows free hand drawing with mouse pointer](http://js.do/rak13/no-tabs)

But,

[this html code with angular material tabs doesn't let any drawing or event on the canvas](http://js.do/rak13/with-angular-material-tabs)

The javascript code (at the end) used  in both the files are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to wait for the angular tabs to load before initializing the canvas.

If canvas is initialized first and then the angular tabs load then the original canvas no more exists.

So, initializing the canvas using setTimeout(some_function_to_init_canvas, 50), would allow enough time for angular tabs to load first.

This works fine, but a callback function would be more preferable.

Answer (score 0):

**First fire angular tab event, then fire fabric event this is work for me**

just set the `setTimeout` funtion for `fabricjs`.multiple tabs also work with this method.

like this

```
function trigger(){
    var canvas =  new fabric.Canvas("myCanvas");
    console.log(canvas);
    canvas.setWidth(400);
    canvas.setHeight(400);
    canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
    console.log(canvas.isDrawingMode);
}

    var drawingapp = angular.module('drawingapp', ['ngMaterial']);
    drawingapp.controller('drawing_controller', function($scope, $http, $log, $document) {

    });
    setTimeout(trigger, 50); //<----- here
```

working [DEMO](http://js.do/code/with-angular-material-tabs)